# gltf shader texture baking help

Tags: shaders, export, gltf

I am trying to export a .gltf model that retains the procedural shaders I've made. When I try exporting, however, the glossiness isn't retained.

[image: what I want]

[image: result]

Notice the sparkles. I want those kept.

I am starting to suspect this isn't doable, but others seem to do it with ease. Is it something to do with my procedural mapping?

Blend-Exchange:
[image]

Please help immediately.

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#exported-materials) is a link to the section on glTF material export in the Blender manual which might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you're trying to bake only a diffuse map. Actually you can skip the diffuse map here; the sparkling effect is produced by spots with low roughness (high reflectivity) and random normals, so what you want here is probably to bake a roughness and normal map. Fortunately that's even easier than diffuse.

### Baking Roughness & Normal Maps

First let's set up a Principled node with the necessary textures. I copied the Principled node out of the RedGlitter group. It's very important to set your image's Color Space to **Non-Color** since Roughness and Normal textures contain data, not colors.

[image]

Now select the Image Texture node connected to Roughness. In the Bake panel, switch the Bake Type to **Roughness** and hit Bake. When it's done, do the same thing for the Image Texture node connected to the Normal Map using the **Normal** Bake Type.

Here's what I got.

[image]

Now connect the Principled node to the Material Output and see how it looks.

[image]

It's pretty good, though not exactly the same. You can export this to glTF now and it will work.

### Looking at the problems

Let's look at it close up.

[image]

- The horizontal artifacts are caused by poor UV unwrapping. Adjacent tris aren't adjacent in the UV map so you get these random UV seams. The super-narrow tris also make this worse. Merging doubles and getting some cleaner UV islands before you bake will clean up most of those.
- The roundness of the sparkles is limited by the resolution of the texture you bake to. Since the sparkles are small compared to the size of the model, even a fairly large texture only allows a few pixels per sparkle. You can bake to a larger texture to improve this. You could also try to take advantage of texture tiling (repeating) to cover a larger area of the model with a smaller texture.